# Does destructuring React functional component props breaks memoization?

Tags: reactjs

For example, if I have this kind of component:

```js
const Component = ({children, ...restProps}) => {
  const style = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      flex: restProps.flex,
      ...restProps.style,
    }),
    [restProps.style]
  );

  {/*....rest component*/}
}
```

Will the destructuring counted as new variable that `React.useMemo` count as different each new render? Thus reassigning the value to `style`?

also, will it affect if I destructure inside the function like:

```js
const Component = (props) => {
  const {children, ...restProps} = props;

  {/*....rest component*/}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the type of the .style property? Primitives are compared by value, and objects - by reference - so there is your answer.

Comment: type of .style is Object. So it will break the memo because it creates new reference right ? @edo.n

Comment: No, destructuring will not create a new reference, but a new reference might be created somewhere in the parent components on each render

Comment: I suggest you find something stable in that style object - for example `rest.style.color` or a combo of two strings that can be compared by value.